# Is it possibile to retrieve org.postgresql.util.PSQLException's cause from IllegalArgumentException inside EJB?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, ejb

I have a project which uses EJB3 and when the code throws an exception related to SQL, it sends a notification to the development team.
So, for example, with this code:

```
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query);
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();
```

if I make a syntax error, I catch the first exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [2] did not exist` which is sent to devs. 
Inside Eclipse I can see other exceptions like `javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` and finally **the last one with the message I want to catch**: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AND"`. Is there a way to get this more details message?
I can see that suppressed exceptions array is empty.

UPDATE: if I insert directly `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` in `catch`, Eclipse states that:

> This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exceptions you see in the Eclipse stracktrace are exceptions stored in the `IllegalArgumentException` forming a chain of error causes.

You can get to the postgres exception by traversing this cause chain:

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Throwable t = e;
    while (t != null)
    {
        if (t instanceof PSQLException) {
              PSQLException pe = (PSQLException)t;
             // analyse the exception
             break;
        }
        t = t.getCause();
    }
}
```